# changing array in excel based on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there anyway to update an array size in excel without altering the formula everytime? For example if I have the formula

```
=sum(A1:A20)
```

and want to update it to

```
=sum(A5:A20)
```

can I do this without manually dragging and typing for example something that would have the same effect as

```
=sum(A(C1):A20)
```

where the value of C1 =5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,C1):A20)
```